# Can't import module keyboard

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard

I tried to install the keyboard module, but this module was not shown to me, but before it's been work.

I tried to install it through "pip install keyboard", but it shows, i have this module:

> PS C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1> pip install keyboard
> Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in
> c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.13.5)
> PS C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1>

Comment: Don't make us click on image links to see the problem.  Post all code and error messages as plain text.

Comment: its likely that your using different versions of python in different tools vs cmd line.   make sure you are adding the package to the correct copy of python.   doing python(3) -m pip install keyboard from the correct python directory will likely install it in the correct place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Requirement already satisfied` basically means that the package you're trying to download is already installed in your computer and all you have to do now is import that package by using the `import` statement. And, if you're curious, global packages are most of the time installed under `/usr/local/bin/` in a Unix-based system, or `\Program Files\` for Windows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This means you have already installed the keyboard module

Comment: I believe they are aware of that but they can't figure out why they are having trouble referencing it to use it.